# How to sort directories based on name which is integer?

Tags: java

I would like to sort list of directories based on numbers. I have directories named like `11-20,1-5,6-10,21-30` etc. Now I want to sort them based on numbers in it so that 1 to N directories come in order I mean in order `1-5,6-10,11-20,21-30`. I am using the following code but it's not working.

```
File[] dirList = mainDir.listFiles();
Arrays.sort(dirList);
```

I am new to file and directory manipulation in Java. What can I try next?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following line :

```
Arrays.sort(dirList);
```

sorts your files using the `File#compareTo()` method, which basically sorts your files by pathname.

You must create a custom implementation of [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) then call :

```
Arrays.sort(dirList, new YourCustomComparator());
```

For example :

```
Comparator<File> comparator = new Comparator<File>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
    /*
     * Here, compare your two files with your own algorithm.
     * Here is an example without any check/exception catch
     */
    String from1 = o1.getName().split("-")[0]; //For '1-5', it will return '1' 
    String from2 = o2.getName().split("-")[0]; //For '11-20', it will return '11'

    //Convert to Integer then compare : 
    return Integer.parseInt(from2)-Integer.parseInt(from1);
  }
}

//Then use your comparator to sort the files:
Arrays.sort(dirList, comparator);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Arnauds answer, if you only want to have directories, you can use a file filter in addition:

```
FileFilter filter = new FileFilter()
{
   public boolean accept(File file) {
     return file.isDirectory();
   }
};

File[] dirList = mainDir.listFiles(filter);
```